# Wordpress - Only the latest post shows up on post page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a custom theme and in the `single.php` file, i have the main loop, however if i navigate to different posts, all that shows up is the latest post. I could go to the different permalinks, but the only post that shows up is the latest one. How do I make it so that the correct post shows up?

I tried changing the permalinks and deleting and adding pages, but I get the same result.
Here is `single.php`

```
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>

<section class="main-section">
    <header>
        <h1 class="section-header"><?php the_category('/');?></h1>
        <ul class="section-nav">
            <?php
                $cat = get_the_category()[0];
                $categoryPosts = get_posts(array('category' => $cat->term_id));

                foreach($categoryPosts as $post): setup_postdata($post);
            ?>

                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <h2 class="section-blurb"><?php the_title();?></h2>
    <div class="info">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</section>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Everything works..but only for the latest post. How do I make it so that the appropriate post is shown?

Comment: Do you want just single static post to show?

Comment: @Aamir no, I want the appropriate post to show when a user navigates to the post. Right now it only shows the latest post. I need it to show the correct one according to the link

Comment: Did you checked it while changing permalinks to default?

Comment: Yes,  I tried it on different permalink settings. All of which yielded the same result.

Answer (score 1):

you can use orderby for sorting order
'orderby'

```
$categoryPosts = get_posts(array('category' => $cat->term_id, 'orderby' => 'post_date',    'order' => ASC));
```

For reference see this link

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: This is not what I was asking.

Comment: Nope! The latest post is always shown no matter which post is supposed to be on the page. I want it to stop having that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it sounds like a simple fix. Is this a child theme. Try saving the current single.php file and replace it with a new single.php file use a wp theme the following is from wp 2012 single.php markup

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                <nav class="nav-single">
                    <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
                    <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?></span>
                    <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>' ); ?></span>
                </nav><!-- .nav-single -->

                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```